# Does SUICIDE also free up stored hashes?

Tags: gas, selfdestruct

Here's a contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract StoreAndFree {
    mapping(int=>int) myStore;
    function StoreAndFree() public {
        for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
            myStore[i] = i;
        }
    }

    function kill() external {
        selfdestruct(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

When you kill it, what happens to the stored values? Are they still stored? Should you reset them to zero? Do you get gas back for resetting them to zero?

Answer (score 1):

The opcode was officially renamed to SELFDESTRUCT in [EIP-6](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-6.md). SELFDESTRUCT, however, wont give you the refund for the rest of the storage. Since storage is actually implemented as a hashmap, the EVM has no way of statically knowing, without being told, which storage slots belong to a contract. If you want the gas refund of resetting storage slots, you'll have to do it manually before calling SELFDESTRUCT.

Note: The max gas refund is half of what you spend, so zeroing a lot of storage slots is likely an altruistic behavior unless it's all happening in a very expensive transaction.

Comment: This conflicts with "the storage and code is removed from the state" at http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Comment: It depends on how you look at it. The SELFDESTRUCT opcode, at the end of the day, doesn't refund you for the storage slots that will no longer be accessible. Nodes can choose to, and do, prune the storage that becomes inaccessible because of a SELFDESTRUCT, but it's not enforced.